# "JAVA_HOME points to an invalid Java installation issue" with service install command in elastic search

Tags: java, php, cmd, elasticsearch

I want to use elastic search with my PHP application.

after running   **service install command** , I am getting fallowing error.

```
C:\elasticsearch-0.90.10\bin>service install
JAVA_HOME points to an invalid Java installation (no java.exe found in "C:\Progr
am Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin"). Existing...
```

Answer (score 8):

Open up and Look into the `service.bat` file:

It searches for:

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe
```

hence your `%JAVA_HOME%` should not include `bin` in it.

A workaround if you do not have privileges to set up the environmental variables:

open the `service.bat` file,

a) *Remove* the line:

```
if NOT DEFINED JAVA_HOME goto err
```

b) *Replace* `%JAVA_HOME%` with your java `jdk` path, something like: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51`

**Note**: This is just a workaround which works all the time.

Answer (score 3):

from your error message we can see your JAVA_HOME points to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin
```

while it should point to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the error message is fairly descriptive , you should look in this folder 
 is java.exe there ? If not then your JAVA_HOME environment variable to point to the correct installation

heres a page showing how to do that 
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Setting+the+JAVA_HOME+Variable+in+Windows

1st hit on google.

Comment: I think My environment variable path is fine. JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin   is there can be problem for above error with elastic search?

Comment: is the executable there though?

Comment: also make sure you have installed the latest bits for the JDK (Java development kit),and the version of JAVA is appropriate for your elastic search installation

Comment: Note this https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/3928
Are you running appropriate version of ES?

Answer (score 1):

Either JAVA_HOME points to the wrong location or you don't have Java installed. Check and see if there's an install of Java in the location specified.

Also note that the JAVA_HOME variable should point to the root of the Java install not the /bin folder. This is being added by the program you're executing.

To change the JAVA_HOME variable to test further use the following in the command prompt:

```
set JAVA_HOME=c:\xxxx
```

Once you've established the correct value to use this can be permanently changed in Control Panel>>System>>Advanced System Settings>>Advanced>>Environment Variables

Comment: Is it a possible permissions problem? Try executing the following from the command prompt you're trying to install in: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin\java.exe

Answer (score 1):

set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java

Above must fix the issue, I came across the same issue while installing the elastic search.
i gave a try by giving "bin" part of path but it did not work, so i just give the top folder "java" in path, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add my own experience.
i was setting JAVA_HOME using tab autocompletion.
It ends up something like "C:\Program files...:" and it didn't work saying that it cannot find the java program. I solved typing the JAVA_HOME path in the set command without using tab completion. The problem was probably related to the " in the env variable